# Implicit function theorem for $f(x,y,z)$: Can I find a function $g$ such that $y=g(x,z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

If I want to use the Implicit function theorem for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Is the order of the variables important?
What I mean with that is, if I can solve $f(x,y,z)$ for $y$?

*[implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Definitions)

Thoughts:

Assuming  $f(a,b,c)=0$ for $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)\neq 0 $ then* $f$ is locally solvable for $y$ i.e. there exist a neighborhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of $(a,c)$ and a continuous differentiable function $g: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $y=g(x,z)$ and $f(x,g(x,z),z)=0$ for every $(x,z)\in U$

But can I use the theorem * like that?

The general form in the theorem is given by: $f:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$

$f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be written as:

a) $f:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m=1,n=2$ if I want to search for a solution $x=g(y,z)$

b)$f:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m=1,n=2$ if I want to search for a solution $z=g(x,y)$.

c) How can I write $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ if I want to search for a solution $y=g(x,z)$ with $m=1$? I cannot identify $n$.

**I'm having some trouble phrasing my question, hopefully it still makes sense to you.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the variables doesn't matter. If it helps, you can just define a new function with the variables in the order you want and then apply the implicit function theorem to the new function:
$$ F(x,z,y) := f(x,y,z).$$